# crawler/spider detection of new site

Tags: web-crawler

I have good development experience using c# and vb.net but I need some guidance. I want to develop spider and crawler like search engine but I do not know how to:

1. how to detect new website in cyber? Like Google detect and crawl site as it is launched?
2. How to detect new pages added to any website? I can detect and parse all pages of website but it is time taking process? How to detect newly added page?
3. How to detect modified page?

Comment: You forgot `java` tag.

Comment: This is a very diverse question, without showing any effort or whatsoever. Good luck anyway

Comment: Detect links to the site from other sites you already crawl is one strategy.

Comment: dupicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314229/how-to-create-a-web-crawler

Comment: Using site maps you can figure out `lastmod`, `changefreq`, and find new pages to index. Also google doesn't always "find" new websites, but rather they are submitted via [link](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url)

Answer (score 1):

following links might be useful

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/build-basic-web-crawler-pull-information-website/

http://www.bitrepository.com/how-to-create-a-simple-web-data-extractor.html

Answer (score 0):

Two main ways to find new pages:

1. Site maps (Google this term to find out more), which can also indicate when a page is updated.
2. Noticing a link to the new site/page on another page that you are crawling.

For a page that you already know about, you can use the "If-Modified-Since" HTTP header, which tells the server to return a 304 response if the page hasn't changed since the date you specify. This saves you downloading and parsing the page again if it hasn't changed, although obviously you've still had to make the request to find this out. That's why site maps are preferred, you get information about the whole site at once. Of course sites aren't required to provide them.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know much c# id start by coding something that runs site:"www.spiderthissite.com" on google and records the /locations/ id also make reg ex that looks through the html of the pages linked also looking for links and folder locations.

however your questions pretty wide id just give it a blast first and then come here when you get stuck at some point.